# Why is there a duplicate variable use in Spring Data JPA and QueryDSL?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

There are a lot of examples online of using QueryDSL like this:

```
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl
    extends QueryDslRepositorySupport
    implements CustomerRepositoryCustom {

 public Iterable<Customer> findAllLongtermCustomersWithBirthday() {
    QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;

    return from(customer)
       .where(hasBirthday().and(isLongTermCustomer()))
       .list(customer);
    }
}
```

This code makes sense, but I am wondering why `customer` is "duplicated" in the method call to `list()`.

Shouldn't the type be obvious from the reference in `from(customer)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` defines the source and `list` the projection. Querydsl query classes don't have any generic type argument for the return type, the projection (select part) is defined in the last part of the query construction chain.

Examples for cases where a different projection than the source is wanted

- specific columns only: `query.list(customer.firstName, customer.lastName)`
- constructor invocation : `Projections.constructor(...)`
- Bean population: `Projections.bean(...)`
- multiple from calls are used

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would use different types for the source and projection?

Comment: Hum, I get the first example, but not the others. I'll mark the answer accepted though since I think it gives plenty of information on where to look for more info.